# Tracking install source in Facebook Analytics with Ionic Framework

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, facebook-analytics

I'm tracking App Events in my app (Ionic v1) using the Javascript method and tracking the default events (Achievement Unlocked, Spent Credits, etc.). All the events I'm tracking are successfully recording in the Events and Events Debugging section of the Analytics.

But when I'm in the Breakdowns section, App Installs and App Launches are tracked automatically whereas the rest are not even though all are predefined events.

And when breaking down by install source, there are only Unknowns and Facebook Organic in the other events even if the Install Source in App Launches and App Installs have Facebook Adverts and Instagram Adverts.

How does the analytics track Install Source?

If a user launches the app through Facebook Adverts, and then triggers another app event, shouldn't Facebook Adverts be one of the Install Sources in the Breakdown for the app event?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "using the Javascript method"? Does Ionic have a plugin for Facebook Analytics, or are you using the Facebook JavaScript SDK in your project?

Comment: I'm using a plugin for Ionic called "cordova-plugin-facebook4" and the Facebook Javascript SDK as well.

Comment: Try logging your other events through cordova-plugin-facebook4 instead of the Javascript SDK. You can get unexpected results if you log some events (App Installs, App Launches) through the native SDKs (which it looks like the plugin is using) and others through the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried logging with the SDK and the plugin, yet they still logged the same way.

Comment: Does the cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin require facebook log in to use only analytics events tracking?